# Why I can't load multiple python scripts containing hooks to C++ application into 1 embedded interpretor

Tags: python, c++

I am following this guide:

http://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html

everything works as described there, until the moment when I want to load more than 1 python script.

My source code is here: https://github.com/huggle/huggle3-qt-lx/blob/ea6e7cafa0b7c57081368ee17a66aaee919d0176/huggle/pythonengine.cpp

Basically what I am trying to do is to create some kind of hooks, that could be optionally "overriden" in the python script that are extending my applications. So that in case of several events that happen in my C++ application, a python hook in extension may be called (if it exist).

So far I am registering hook called `hook_main_window_is_loaded` that is to be called when main window finish loading, so that python extensions can do something. I am doing it using

```
    // load symbols for hooks now
    this->ptr_Hook_MainLoaded = PyObject_GetAttrString(this->object, "hook_main_window_is_loaded");
    if (this->ptr_Hook_MainLoaded != NULL && !PyCallable_Check(this->ptr_Hook_MainLoaded))
    { ...
```

(line 171)

**it works** great as long as I am loading only 1 python script. It doesn't matter if this script has this function (let's call it *MainWindowHook*):

```
def hook_main_window_is_loaded():
    print ("called hook_main_window_is_loaded");
```

or not. However, if I load more than 1 script, it only works when both of them have this *MainWindowHook* implemented. If first one does not have it, then for unknown reasons fail to load the second script o.O with following error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'hook_main_window_is_loaded'
Thu Feb 20 10:22:02 2014   Failed to load a python script: extensions/ext2.py
```

This would make sense, if the first one failed to load (because that is one which doesn't contain the *MainWindowHook*), but if I have only first python script (even with no definition of *MainWindowHook*) it still works.

In simple words:

- When I have only 1 python script to load, it works no matter if *MainWindowHook* is there or not (This is normal and expected)
- When I have more than 1, it works only if all of them contain *MainWindowHook* (not expected)
- When I have 2 of them, it works even if first which is loaded contains *MainWindowHook* but second not (really weird)

Why is that? How can I load more than 1 script so that I don't need to have this definition in all scripts?

EDIT: I figured out there is a workaround for this:

When I read the entire source code file (.py) and use regex to check if the function definition is there and call `PyObject_GetAttrString` only if regex find the definition there, it works. However it's a nasty thing which may not work well and creates extra overhead, while according to python documentation, the function `PyObject_GetAttrString` should return `NULL` in case there is no such a function (it doesn't do that).